# mapbox append values to form on map click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using mapbox and I am inserting a marker on map click, however I also want to append those values in a form so I could use my controller in order to store these values.

Marker is being added and values are appended however,

[image]

in the last value where is says LngLat(-1) etc, after a comma it appends " which should ve after closing bracket ) how can it be removed?

```
       <div id="right" class="map">
            <div id='map' class="map" style='width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;'></div>
            <script>
            mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibGl2ZS1vbGRoYW0iLCJhIjoiY2ozbXk5ZDJ4MDAwYjMybzFsdnZwNXlmbyJ9.VGDuuC92nvPbJo-qvhryQg';
            var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
                        center: [-1.77, 52.73],
                        zoom: 3
            });
                        map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
                        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
                    }));
                        map.on('click', function (e) {
                        var lng = e.lngLat.lng;
                        var lat = e.lngLat.lat;
                        var lngLat = e.lngLat;
                        $( ".append").append( "<input type=hidden name=lng value="+lng+">");
                        $( ".append").append( "<input type=hidden name=lat value="+lat+">");
                        $( ".append").append( "<input type=hidden name=lngLat value="+lngLat+">");
                        new mapboxgl.Marker()
                        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
                        .addTo(map);
});
            </script>
                            <form class="append" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ action('BusinessController@saveMarkers') }}">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                  Save Marker
                </button>
                            </form>
```

Comment: Do you mind showing the value of `lngLat`, with a console.log for example? Or even better create a working example of the scenario (snippet, jsfiddle)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv1lk.jpg

Comment: That is already on your question body. What I meant is if you can also show the value of the variable `lngLat`, the one from `"<input type=hidden name=lngLat value="+lngLat+">"`

Comment: it's on first screenshot. that is the value of lngLat

Comment: Can you do `console.log(lngLat)` and show us the output from the console?

Comment: It is the link i have given above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146260/discussion-between-freeman-lambda-and-przemek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line

```
$( ".append").append( "<input type=hidden name=lngLat value="+lngLat+">");
```

jQuery is trying to parse the string inside `append` into valid html. Valid html means that attributes need to be wrapped in `"` quotes. Thus jQuery tries to turn `type=hidden` into `type="hidden"` and so on. This works fine for simple cases, but it is not working well for the line where the problem occurs.

To solve this issue, I think it is best to make jQuery's work easier, by constructing better html, that is easier to parse:

```
'<input type="hidden" name="lngLat" value="LngLat {lng: ' + lngLat.lng + ', lat: ' + lngLat.lat + '}">'
```